# how to import data from SQLITE to excel using xlsxwriter in python

Tags: python, excel, sqlite, xlsxwriter

```
import sqlite3
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
workbook = Workbook('output2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

conn=sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("select * from abc")
mysel=c.execute("select * from abc ")
for row in mysel:
 print row
 worksheet.write(0, 0, row[0])
workbook.close()
```

here is layout of SQLITE database table

```
id  sno
1   100
2   200
3   300
4   400
```

with worksheet.write(0, 0, row[0]) i get output as **4** in First cell of excel file.

with worksheet.write(0, 0, row[1]) i get output as **400** in First cell of excel file

am not able to figure out the **FOR LOOP** issue.

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop is fine except that you are writing each row of data into the same cell. I don't know xlswriter but I guess the first and second parameters are the row and column. If you want to write all the data as a table you will need to change these on each write operation.

Something like this (untested)?

```
import sqlite3
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
workbook = Workbook('output2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

conn=sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("select * from abc")
mysel=c.execute("select * from abc ")
for i, row in enumerate(mysel):
    print row
    worksheet.write(i, 0, row[0])
    worksheet.write(i, 1, row[1])
workbook.close()
```

To handle multiple columns you could do this

```
import sqlite3
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
workbook = Workbook('output2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

conn=sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("select * from abc")
mysel=c.execute("select * from abc ")
for i, row in enumerate(mysel):
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        worksheet.write(i, j, value)
workbook.close()
```

Comment: thanks it works. please advise how i can tweak this for loop to handle n number of rows and columns. e.g instead of 4 rows i have thousand of rows and 15 columns to dump in the sheet from sqlite

Comment: Good answer. Just to note that as an alternative the inner for loop could be written as `write_row(i, 0, row)`

Comment: presumably you mean worksheet.write_row(i, 0, row). Upvote if you like the answer ;-)

Comment: hahah, yes you right sir,  worksheet.write_row(i, 0, row) is the correct thing

Comment: Correct `worksheet.write_row()`. I did upvote :-). And @ashir_nasir should accept since this is a good answer.

Comment: @ashirnasir the question is still marked as having no accepted answer. Please accept my answer as correct.

Answer (score 4):

```
import sqlite3
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
workbook = Workbook('output2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

conn=sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("select * from abc")
mysel=c.execute("select * from abc ")
for i, row in enumerate(mysel):
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        worksheet.write(i, j, row[j])
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating many CSVs sheets in the same file, you can create a XLSX file with many sheets.
Depending on your needs, it can be a great solution.
Here's what I've got.

```
import sqlite3
import xlsxwriter
from tkinter import filedialog # Used to get a path where to save the new excel file
from datetime import datetime # Used to name the file with today's date

DB_Path = filedialog.askdirectory() # OPTIONAL: Asks to select folder path
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(DB_Path+"/"+"MyDatabaseInExcel  "+datetime.now().strftime("%Y %m %d")+'.xlsx') # Create file
conn = sqlite3.connect('MyDatabaseInSQLite3.db') # Connect to your database
cursor = conn.cursor() # Create the cursor
tables = list(cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")) # Get all table names
tables = list(map(lambda x: x[0], tables)) # convert the list of tuple to list of str
for table in tables:
    try: worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(name=table[0:31]) # Sheet names in excel can have up to 31 chars
    except:pass
    for row_number, row in enumerate(cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM '+table)): # row is a tuple here
        for column_number, item in enumerate(row):
            try: worksheet.write(row_number, column_number, item) # Write the cell in the current sheet
            except:pass
workbook.close() # Saves the new document
```

I used some try just to prevent cracking the program for any reason and not to write the other sheets. For me it was interesting at a time in my project. If you want, you can not use it.